# Visualize occurrence of value

Tags: javascript, database, canvas, data-visualization

I have a Dataset (~ 100mb) and want to get a better understanding of the data by first visualizing the amount of different JSON values.

I started by drawing an arc with `ctx.arc();` and increasing the radius for each occurrence of a value.

```
switch(data[i].value) {
        case "X":
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, 100, i+1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "MidnightBlue";
            ctx.fill();
            break;
}
```

The arc is drawn but way to big and goes beyond my viewport. So it seems that a) I'm making a mistake or b) there are just to much occurrences of the value, which cause the circle to become gigantic. How could I counter that problem?

Comment: What is your data like? looks like you draw each circle with a radius of `i+1`, if `i` is the index, not surprising that circles will grow very big.

Answer (score 1):

### Visualizing large values

There are two ways to visualize data that has large values.

You have given no clue as to the structure of the data so mostly I am just guessing about the data.

#### Scale and translate.

If the distribution of values is roughly linear you can scale and move the values to fit within the needed range.

To do this you go thought all the data points one at a time and find the minimum value and max value.

```
var min = Infinity;  // set the start min and max
var max = -Infinity;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     if (data[i].value === "X") {
         // I dont know where you got the x from so leave that to you
         // x is the value needed to graph
         min = Math.min(min, x);
         max = Math.max(max, x);
     }
}
```

After you have check each value and have a min and max you need to workout how big you want to display the info.

```
const displayMaxRadius = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 2;
const displayMinRadius = 10;
```

Then to display each value you use the min and max to scale to a normalized range, bringing each value to be within 0 to 1 inclusive. The scale to fit te display min and max

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
     if (data[i].value === "X") {
         // I dont know where you got the x from so leave that to you
         // x is the value needed to graph
         var norm = (x - min) / (max - min); // normalize the value
         var displaySize = norm * (displayMaxRadius - displayMinRadius) + displayMinRadius;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(displaySize , 100, i + 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         ctx.fillStyle = "MidnightBlue";
         ctx.fill();
```

#### Logarithmic data

Sometimes the range of values is spread unevenly over a very large range, with clumps of data at some ranges. Using the above method will work but for most of the data it will be scaled such that the individual differences are lost due to the large range of values.

To deal with that you create a logarithmic graph, simple find the root of the values before you find the min max range. You can use the square root or to any other value.

Use `Math.pow(x,1/r)` where r is to what root you want r = 2 is square root, r = 3 is cubic root, and so on

```
var root = 2; // sqrt root
var min = Infinity;  // set the start min and max
var max = -Infinity;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if (data[i].value === "X") {
         // I dont know where you got the x from so leave that to you
         // x is the value needed to graph
         var rval = Math.pow(x, root);
         min = Math.min(min, rval);
         max = Math.max(max, rval);
     }
}
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if (data[i].value === "X") {
         // I dont know where you got the x from so leave that to you
         // x is the value needed to graph
         var rval = Math.pow(x, root);
         var norm = (rval - min) / (max - min); // normalize the value
         var displaySize = norm * (displayMaxRadius - displayMinRadius) + displayMinRadius;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(displaySize , 100, i + 1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
         ctx.fillStyle = "MidnightBlue";
         ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort of found an answer to my question myself. What I could do is create a grid/rectangle with modulo.

```
var x = (i % 115) * 1; 
var y = Math.floor(i / 115) * 1; 

ctx.fillStyle = "MidnightBlue"; 
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

As you can see I have key/value pairs of the states in the US. To visualize the occurrence of each state in the dataset I want to draw a grid with modulo. 
The number 115 is the root of 13450. But 13450 is the amount of (for example) all farms in the US. Now I want to visualize just the farms in PA … How could I do that?